# What is this curiosity in the Area51 "Radical" badge?

Tags: support, area-51, badges

When I opened the Area51 page today, I was notified of a newly-earned "Radical" badge. Curious. The question that earned it is [Where is the "turbo" button on my PC?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4239/computer-hardware/21042#21042)

I thought perhaps I had received 10 or 15 total on/off-topic votes on my questions. The mouseover, however, says ["First question with 3 off-topic votes"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/202/radical?userid=19956"). Obviously, that is not the case---the first two votes were "off-topic", and the third was "on-topic".

It seems the calculation simply checks the first vote and then increments for every vote thereafter.

**Edit:** I apologize, this was merely a case of a repealed vote. I do have great faith in the programming behind the site.

Comment: We appreciate that you have faith in the code behind the site, but don't hesitate to tell us if you see something that you think is wrong and you can't come up with why. We want to hear about it. Even if something's not wrong with the code, many people are probably going to have the same question. :D

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement, @CrazyJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badge aren't revoked. This mean that if someone clicked on off-topic button then decide to undo his vote, you can still be awarded the Radical badge and this badge won't be revoked. In your case, this is probably what did happen.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks. I should have known! Earlier I had thought about this kind of thing (and you could actually get badges like "Critic" without a downvote on your record by clicking on it again before the window expired---but that was fixed a while ago, I think).